# selection sort in python

Tags: python, sorting, selection-sort

Here's a code for selection sort but it doesn't print the sorted list. How can I show it?

```
badlist = input("Enter list: ")  
def select(badlist):  
        l = list[:]  
        sorted = []  
        while len(l):  
            lowest == l[0]  
            for x in l:  
                if x < lowest:  
                    lowest = x  
            sorted.append(lowest)  
            l.remove(lowest)  
        return sorted  
select(badlist)
```

Comment: there is no print statement in the code try `print select(badlist)`

Comment: I wonder what is happening here `l = list[:]`; don't name your variables the same as builtins. `sorted = []` and then `sorted.append(lowest)` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: why not simply use the builtin `sorted(list)` and then you can just have your whole code be: `print sorted(input("Enter list: "))`

Comment: As a side note, your implementation doesn't appear correct. Selection sort is an _inplace_ algorithm, so you're supposed to use one single list for both sorted and unsorted parts (hint: swap min and current items instead of removing/appending).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`print`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement).

If you are using Python 2.x `print` is a keyword:

```
result = select(badlist)
print result
```

In Python 3.x `print` is a function and you must use parentheses:

```
result = select(badlist)
print(result)
```

You also have at least two other errors:

- Your function parameter is called `badlist` but you never use it.
- The `==` operator is equality comparison. You need `=` for assignment.

Also your algorithm will be very slow, requiring O(n<sup>2</sup>) operations.

Comment: It produces a TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__geitem__' :(

Answer (score 2):

if you type `select(badlist)` in Python shell is should show the result however if you're running your script as file you need to use `print` statement, as `print select(badlist)`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment:

Why not simply use the builtin [`sorted(list)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and then you can just have your whole code be:

`print sorted(input("Enter list: "))`

Comment: I'm sure this is an assignment or homework, and they aren't allowed to use built-ins.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid while that may be the case, it is not stated, and regardless, this answer is not ONLY for the OP, but an answer to anyone coming to StackOverflow looking for a solution to a problem similar to the OP and finding this page. It would be wrong not to include this as an answer.