# Selection Sort Python

Tags: python, sorting

This may seem like a simple question but when I attempted to implement selection sort in Python, I do not get a sorted list. Is there something wrong with my implementation? The subsetting may be a problem.

```
source = [4,2,1,10,5,3,100]
for i in range(len(source)):
  mini = min(source[i:]) #find minimum element
  min_index = source[i:].index(mini)-1 #find index of minimum element
  source[i:][min_index]= source[i:][0] #replace element at min_index with first element
  source[i:][0] = mini                  #replace first element with min element
print source
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [selection sort in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685915/selection-sort-in-python)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think there were a couple issues.

First, when your do source[i:], I believe that returns a new array of the sub-elements requested and not part of the original array, thus if you modify it, your don't modify the original. Second, you were subtracting 1 from an index when you shouldn't.

```
source = [4,2,1,10,5,3,100]
for i in range(len(source)):
    mini = min(source[i:]) #find minimum element
    min_index = source[i:].index(mini) #find index of minimum element
    source[i + min_index] = source[i] #replace element at min_index with first element
    source[i] = mini                  #replace first element with min element
print source
```

This gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 100]
```

Comment: instead of finding min_index from source[1:].index try finding by source.index,
this would simplify your next step of swap,
just swap using 
source[i],source[min_index] = source[min_index], source[i].

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would rewrite your code.  Of course in Python I would just use `list.sort()` to sort a list, but here is a selection sort in Python.

We make a generator expression that returns tuples of `(value, i)` for a value and its index from the list.  Then when `min()` evaluates to find minimum, it finds the lowest tuple value; since the value comes first in the tuple before the index, the value will be the important part, and `min()` will find the lowest value.  (If there is a tie, `min()` will use the second part of the tuple, the index, as a tie-breaker.  But for sort we don't care how ties are broken.)

Now, instead of searching through the sub-list to find the min value, and then searching through it again to figure out the index, we search through it once and get both min value and index.

But we don't actually care about the min value; we care about the index.  So after `min()` is done, we just throw away the actual value but keep the index.  Adjust the index to be correct in the whole list (not in the slice of the list) and then we can swap.

We use the standard Python idiom for swapping two values.  Python will build a tuple object to be the intermediate, then unpack this tuple into the left-hand-side.

```
lst = [4,2,1,10,5,3,100]

for i_sortpos in range(len(lst)):
    # Make a generator expression to return (value, i) pairs.
    genexp = ((n, i) for i, n in enumerate(lst[i_sortpos:]))
    # Use genexp with min() to find lowest and its index.
    # (Use '_' for variable name for the actual value; we don't use it.)
    _, i_min = min(genexp)
    # Adjust index to be correct in full list.
    i_min += i_sortpos
    # Swap the number at i_sortpos with the lowest found.
    lst[i_sortpos], lst[i_min] = lst[i_min], lst[i_sortpos]

print(lst)
```

EDIT: And here is a refinement of the above.  A slice from a list actually allocates a new list; our code here doesn't need a new list, it just needs a convenient way to examine a sublist.  The `itertools` module offers a function, `islice()`, that returns an iterator that iterates over a slice of a list.  This avoids repeatedly creating and destroying lists as we examine each sublist.

I believe this is the most efficient way to do selection sort in Python.  (You could get rid of the part where we bind the generator expression to the name `genexp` and save a few microseconds... just make the call to `min()` a long one-liner.  But it's not really worth the loss of readability.)

```
import itertools as it

lst = [4,2,1,10,5,3,100]

for i_sortpos in range(len(lst)):
    # Make a generator expression to return (value, i) pairs.
    # Use it.islice() for to look at sublist.
    genexp = ((n, i) for i, n in enumerate(it.islice(lst, i_sortpos, len(lst))))
    # Use genexp with min() to find lowest and its index.
    # (Use '_' for variable name for the actual value; we don't use it.)
    _, i_min = min(genexp)
    # Adjust index to be correct in full list.
    i_min += i_sortpos
    # Swap the number at i_sortpos with the lowest found.
    lst[i_sortpos], lst[i_min] = lst[i_min], lst[i_sortpos]

print(lst)
```

Comment: Is `_, i_min = min(genexp)` not wrong **?** `min(genexp)` will consider index also to compare, may should be rectified something as `min(genexp, lambda key: key[0])` ... thought I learned quite a lot from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I discussed the issue you raised, in the second paragraph.  `min()` on tuples will compare the items at index 0 in the tuple, but then use the items at index 1 in case of a tie; for sorting we don't care how the tie is resolved, so it works fine.  By the way, Python provides a cool feature you can use instead of that lambda expression: `operator.itemgetter()` is a slightly faster way to get an item from a particular index.

Answer (score 1):

```
def selectionSort(List_):
    for i in range(len(List_)):`
        #track the current smallest value
        smallIndex = i
            #loop from the current smallest value
            for j in range(i+1,len(List_))
                if List_[j] < List_[smallIndex]:
                    #if new value is less that our smallest value,change 
                    #smallest value to this
                    smallIndex = j
            if smallIndex != i:
                #swap the values
                List_[smallIndex],List_[i] = List_[i],List_[smallIndex]
    #return sorted list
    return List_
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def ss(l):    
    for i in range(0,len(l)):
        d=l.index(min(l[i:]))        
        c=l[i]
        l[i]=min(l[i:])
        l[d]=c
        print(l)  #it prints each step of selection sort
y=[10,9,1,5,0,6]
ss(y)
```

Comment: [0, 9, 1, 5, 10, 6]
[0, 1, 9, 5, 10, 6]
[0, 1, 5, 9, 10, 6]
[0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 9]
[0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 10] #this is output

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ?

Comment: what i m doing is taking min value of list and replacing it with first element and replacing the first element with min value element.So only changes occur in position of min value and first element and rest of element remains same.Now when 2nd time loop will work it will start from 2nd position of list and same thing happens till end.There for only one loop required.For graphical analysis visit the below link
link:  : http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/animation/web/SelectionSort.html

Answer (score 0):

```
def selSort(L):
    """
    Find the smallest element in the list and put it (swap it) in the first location, 
    Find the second element and put it (swap it) in the second locaiton, and so on. 

    """
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        minIndx = i
        minVal= L[i]
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(L):
            if minVal > L[j]:
                minIndx = j
                minVal= L[j]
            j += 1
        temp = L[i]
        L[i] = L[minIndx]
        L[minIndx] = temp 
    return L
```

Call:

```
print( selSort([120,11,0,1,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) )
```

Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 120]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [1,8,4,9,3,6,2]
for i in range(len(s)):
    maxi = max(s[0:len(s)-i])     #find max element
    tempi = s.index(maxi)         # find index of max element
    temp = s[len(s)-1-i]          #assign last element as temp
    s[len(s)-1-i] = maxi          #put max element in last position
    s[tempi] = temp               # put the element initially at last in its new 

print s
```

Comment: Two problems: 1. `max` function is better reimplemented to make `max` and `index` one operation, since the built in `max` and `index` are both O(n) operations. 2. You can use multi-value assignment instead creating an extra temp variable to swap the largest and the tail elements.

Answer (score 0):

Find the position(first and last), swap the elements if last is lower.

```
nums = [4,2,1,10,5,3,100]
def sort(nums):
     ###Find the position and now first 0th element is sorted and rest is unsorted
    #Second iteration first 2 element is sorted
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        miniposition = i
        for j in range(i,len(nums)):
            if nums[j] < nums[miniposition]:
                miniposition = j
        temp = nums[i]
        nums[i] = nums[miniposition]
        nums[miniposition] = temp
sort(nums)
print (nums)
```

First iteration(swapped 4 and 1)
    `[1, 2, 4, 10, 5, 3, 100]`

```
[1, 2, 4, 10, 5, 3, 100]
[1, 2, 3, 10, 5, 4, 100]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 100]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 100]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 100]
```

Other way

```
nums = [4,2,1,10,5,3,100]
i = 0
while i<len(nums):
    #smallest element in the sublist
    smallest = min(nums[i:])
    #index of smallest element
    index_of_smallest = nums.index(smallest)
    #swapping
    nums[i],nums[index_of_smallest] = nums[index_of_smallest],nums[i]
    i=i+1
print (nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

a slight variation of the solution provided

```
def selection_sort(l):
i = 0
while i < len(l):
    minium_value = min(l[i:]) # minium value at ith iteration
    minium_value_index = l[i:].index(minium_value) # minium value index at i th iteration

    if minium_value < l[i]: # if the current value already min, skip
        l[i + minium_value_index] = l[i] # put current value in min value's index - swap 1
        l[i] = minium_value # set current value with min value- swap 2
    i += 1

return l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def selection_sort_min(): # sorting number

    for i in range(len(num)-1):
        current_min_index = i
        for j in range(i+1,len(num)):
            if  num[j] < num[current_min_index] :
                current_min_index = j
        num[i],num[current_min_index] = num [current_min_index],num[i]
    print(num)
num = [23,89,12,0,3,7,33]

selection_sort_min()
```

Comment: this is essentially a copy of @Amjad's answer. Stop necrobumping, please...

Answer (score -1):

here is what I think is a good way to sort a list of numbers and I hope it helps:

```
list=[5,4,3,1,6,8,10,9]
listsorted=[]
for i in range(len(list)):
    x=min(list)
    list.remove(x)
    listsorted.append(x)
print listsorted
```

and the result will be [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]

Comment: But the algorithm is not doing a in place sort which is the purpose of selection sort

Answer (score -1):

I think the "accepted" answer here is unhelpful.  If we look at e.g.

```
mini = min(source[i:]) #find minimum element
min_index = source[i:].index(mini) #find index of minimum element
```

not only is this inefficient in terms of creating list slices unnecessarily, but they are searched unnecessarily.  It's reasonably concise but I don't think it's the best solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
def Selection_Sort(Sarray):
    length = len(Sarray)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(length):
        j = i+1
        for j in range(length):
            if Sarray[i] < Sarray[j]
                t = Sarray[i]
                Sarray[i] = Sarray[j]
                Sarray[j] = t
        j = j+1
        i = i+1

    return Sarray
```

Comment: Please put some description of how your answer finds the problem in the code in the question, not just an alternate implementation of the selection sort.

Answer (score -2):

**Code of select sort from MIT online course .**

```
def selSort(L):
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        minIndx = i
        minVal = L[i]
        j = i+1
        while j < len(L):
            if minVal > L[j]:
                minIndx = j
                minVal = L[j]
            j += 1
        if minIndx != i:
            temp = L[i]
            L[i] = L[minIndx]
            L[minIndx] = temp
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def selectSort(L):
  for i in range(len(L)):
    print L
    minIndex = i
    minValue = L[i]
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(L):
        if minValue > L[j]:
            minIndex = j
            minValue = L[j]  
        j +=1
    temp = L[i]
    L[i] = L[minIndex]
    L[minIndex] = temp
```